# Edit formatting buttons broken in grayscale mobile view

Tags: bug, status-bydesign, mobile-web

The edit buttons on answer boxes in the grayscale mobile view are broken, but not missing. The dividers show up, but the buttons don't. (I am on iPhone now, so I can't load a screenshot.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ThIs is correct, we suppress the WMD editor on mobile devices.

Comment: I know that the formatting buttons are suppressed, but I was seeing the dividers though. Thought it a bug.